# SystemParametersInfo returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    LPWSTR test = L"C:/aizen.png";
    int result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, test, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
    if(result)
        cout << "Wallpaper set!";
    else
        cout << "NOOOOO!" << result;
    cin >> result;
    return 0;
}
```

Very simple code, but result returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try `GetLastError()` to find out what's wrong

Comment: [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) say "**Note**  When the `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` flag is used, `SystemParametersInfo` always returns `TRUE`."

Comment: @Carl The documentation is telling a great big fat lie!

Comment: The documentation also tells, about the third parameter: *"A parameter whose usage and format depends on the system parameter being queried or set. For more information about system-wide parameters, see the uiAction parameter. If not otherwise indicated, **you must specify NULL** for this parameter. For information on the PVOID datatype, see Windows Data Types."* And nothing is specified for `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER`. Maybe a missing flag?

Comment: NULL is 0 under Windows.  It doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: I found out that if SystemParametersInfo and GetLastError both return 0, it may be an image format error. I tested it myself and SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER does not accept png’s and version 1 bmp’s. But it does accept jpg’s and version 3 bmp’s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do what the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) says, and call `GetLastError` to find out the reason behind the error.

Some possible causes spring to mind:

- `SystemParametersInfo` does not like forward slashes as separators.
- The system doesn't like .png files for wallpaper.
- The file doesn't exist.
- You have an ANSI/Unicode encoding mismatch.
- You don't have rights to modify the wallpaper.

Really, the list is endless. So let the system tell you.

---

Note that the documentation says:

> When the `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` flag is used, `SystemParametersInfo` always returns `TRUE`.

But this is a great big fat lie. It's trivially easy to call the function, pass `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER`, and receive `FALSE` in return.

Comment: which means file not found, but the file is in there!

Comment: Replace the `/` with a backslash `\\`

Comment: I replaced it with '\' and '\\' none of them worked! :( I changed the directory to desktop (just in case if it was privilege issues) and still didn't work...

Comment: I've evaluated all the bullet points and come up empty on my own attempts at this.  It doesn't matter whether I call the A or W version, whether I use / or \ (Windows Imaging Component accepts either, as does GetFileAttributes), the file exists because I test for that before calling SystemParametersInfo, and I get error 0.  I'm an admin on the box, so I can change the wallpaper (otherwise the error code would be Access Denied, wouldn't it?).  It's not that the settings preclude using an image--and by the way, Win7 loves PNGs as wallpaper, that's not it either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know with the information we have.

This return value indicates that the call failed. You'll need to call `GetLastError()` for information about why.

Comment: GetLastError() returns 2 (file not found) but he file is in there!