# GetLastError returns error 2 in SystemParametersInfo

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    LPWSTR test = L"c:/aizen.png";
    int result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, test, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
    if(result)
        cout << "Wallpaper set!";
    else
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
    cin >> result;
    return 0;
}
```

The code is simply meant to change the background wallpaper, but I keep getting Error: 2, which means "file not found". However, the file is there! I'm using microsoft visual studio 2010 and I've tried running as admin, case-sensitive, changing slashes, etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is C:/ ?? Change to C:\\aizen.png

Comment: Please read the question carefully: I stated that I've tried this and did not work out.

Comment: Do you have UNICODE defined? If not, you'll end up calling the ANSI-version of SystemParametersInfo with a Unicode string, so it will end up treating the filename as "c"... SystemParamatersInfo is tricky like that as the pvParam is void*, so there's no CHAR vs WCHAR type checking that you'd get with other strongly typed APIs. Try calling the Unicode version, SystemParamtersInfoW, explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Error 2 is `File not found`.

First, make sure that `aizen.png` is actually located in the root folder of drive `C:\` (which on Vista and above is not likely, given that non-admin users don't typically have write access there).

If the file is indeed there, the problem is most likely that you're not properly escaping backslashes:

```
LPWSTR test = L"c:\\aizen.png";
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully: I stated that I've tried this and did not work out.

Comment: Your question says "tried to change the slashes". It says nothing about escaping backslashes, which is the proper solution. If that doesn't work, the file doesn't exist where you think it does.

Comment: @DarrenSadr, as Ken said, a) your file is not located in C drive with that name b) You've not escaped backslashes properly. Check everything once again

Comment: Sorry about being unclear in the question. However, I tried changing the forward slash to double backslash, and still got the same error. However, compiling with mingw g++ solved it with some modifications. I'll post my answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: But it didn't work with Visual Studio 2010 regardless. I assure you that the file was there and the escaping slashes made no change.

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code, it successfully changed my background. I re-checked the code, re-checked on WinXP and Win7, it still works. Make sure there is no administrative access problem, try running your code with another path, try running using administrative privilege (maybe?), but simply it works here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing a UNICODE string - `LPWSTR` - to an API that takes ANSI.

Nearly all Win32 APIs (all that take strings at any rate) come in two versions, one that ends in ...A for ANSI (8-bit characters), and one that ends in ...W for Wide-char, aka UNICODE (technically not 'real' unicode, but that's more than is worth getting in this reply).

If you have UNICODE `#define`d at compilation time, then the plain unadorned version gets #defined as the ...W version; otherwise it gets #defined as the ...A version. Take a look at winuer.h, and you'll see:

```
WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
SystemParametersInfoA(
    __in UINT uiAction,
    __in UINT uiParam,
    __inout_opt PVOID pvParam,
    __in UINT fWinIni);
WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
SystemParametersInfoW(
    __in UINT uiAction,
    __in UINT uiParam,
    __inout_opt PVOID pvParam,
    __in UINT fWinIni);
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SystemParametersInfo  SystemParametersInfoW
#else
#define SystemParametersInfo  SystemParametersInfoA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Note that Windows has *two* SystemParametersInfo functions; the W one expects wide LPWSTR and the A one expect plain LPSTRs; and whether you have UNICODE defined or not selects which is the 'default' one. (You can always add the A or W manually to call either explicitly.)

What's likely happening in your original code is that because you do not have UNICODE defined, you end up using the ...A version, which expects an ANSI string, but you're passing in a UNICODE string - so it doesn't work.

The "bit of a change" you made to get it working is more than just a bit: you're now passing an ANSI string to the ...A version of the API so it works fine:

```
int result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)"c:/aizen.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Alternatively, you could call the W version explicitly with a LPWSTR:

```
int result = SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, L"c:\\aizen.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Or, you could define UNICODE at the start of your app, use L"..." strings, and the plain version of the APIs - just add #define UNICODE at the top of your original app before #include . (UNICODE is more usually defined in a makefile or in compiler settings options instead of being defined explicitly in code, so if you're new to Win32 programming, it can come as something of a surprise feature.)

Note that LPWSTR is *not* deprecated; if anything, it's the opposite; typical Win32 practice since XP or so has been to use W-flavor strings across the board, so it's effectively the plain "..." strings that are considered 'deprecated' on Win32. (For example, many COM APIs use only wide strings.)

Most other functions have some protection against this; if you accidentally try to pass an ANSI string to say SetWindowTextW, you'll get a compile-time error, because the LPSTR you are passing in doesn't match the expcted LPWSTR type the function is expecting. But SystemParamtersInfo is tricky; it takes a void* for the data parameter, so will accept [almost] *anything* at compile time, and it's only when you call the function at runtime that you'll hit the error.

--

This, by the way, is what David Herfernan pointed out in the [answer to your question the first time you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14634949/660175) -

> Some possible causes spring to mind:
>
> ...
>
> - You have an ANSI/Unicode encoding mismatch.

Answer (score -1):

It's very weird looks like if you compile with MinGW c++ compiler it actually compiles this with a bit of change:

```
int main(){
        int result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)"c:/aizen.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

This would work, and apparently LPWSTR is deprecated...
Visual Studio was probably having privilege issues. Run it as Admin and try again.

Comment: Hrm, I didn't downvote - and shame on the downvoter for not saying why they were doing so. Anyway, it looks like the issue is that you were calling an ANSI function with a unicode string, so it failed; now you're calling an ANSI function with an ANSI string, so it's working. Better fix is to call a wide/unicode function with a wide/unicode string. See my answer for more detailed explanation.

Comment: I don't understand. What's wrong with the answer? It provides correct code and the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Some possible issues with your answer; the issue is not "very weird", nor has LPWSTR been deprecated nor has the issue anything to do with privilege issues. Do read my answer for an explanation of why your original code didn't work and why your change here fixes it. Writing code is more than just changing things till they seem to work; having an understanding of why things don't work or work is important.